# Launching EC Instance :: A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the RunInstances operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am using AWS CLI and have already configured it using `AWS Configure`
when i launch an EC2 instance using :

```
C:\>aws ec2 run-instances --dry-run --image-id ami-b5a7ea85 --count 1 --instance
-type t2.micro --key-name ec2_key --iam-instance-profile Arn=arn:aws:iam::132895
064974:instance-profile/ec2Admin
```

It is giving me :

```
A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the RunInstances op
eration: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization
 failure message: 4doSfAQy0gcqKr1O-raIb0C83C2kLWQY8hjZ4gVtwUz6xSAwOtD2wumVnpgsz5
```

Comment: The command was correct, what actually happened was i made a group for administrative ec2 access, but didn't add my user to that group that was causing the problem. Hence problem solved !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do you know what this means?

```
--iam-instance-profile Arn=arn:aws:iam::132895064974:instance-profile/ec2Admin
```

If you are launching an EC2 instance with an IAM role, then you need to have IAM administrative privilege. It is discussed in detail [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/545546/how-to-specify-an-iam-role-for-an-amazon-ec2-instance-being-launched-via-the-aws)

You can also try to decode the error message and see what it says:

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message 4doSfAQy0gcqKr1O-raIb0C83C2kLWQY8hjZ4gVtwUz6xSAwOtD2wumVnpgsz5
```

Comment: my command was correct, what actually happened was i made a group for administrative ec2 access, but didn't add my user to that group that was causing the problem. Thanx !

Comment: so basically what your answer pointed to was happening, as i have mentioned the problem in the comment above that i was having so please add that as a part of your answer (as a special case) and i will accept it.

Comment: What about if you get an error trying to decode the message?

Comment: @mathtick do you know you can add a comment or ask further questions without downvoting

Comment: Yes, I guess I view downvoting as less about "this answer is not good" and more about "this answer is not the most general most useful answer that includes all possible reasons people could end up here". So it *really* is not personal. It is about the entire chain from google search to landing here.